# Pandas: Date Format Changes from mmmyy to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame column in **mmmyy** format and would like to change in **yyyy-mm-dd** format.

Input :

```
         Date
         Aug21
         Sept21
```

Output:

```
         Date
        2021-08-01
        2021-09-01
```

tried: `conv = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%b %y")`

```
dfi["Date"] = dfi["Date"].apply(conv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sept` doesn't match the `%b` format as only 3 letters are valid.

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('Sept21', '%b%y')
# ValueError: time data 'Sept21' does not match format '%b%y'

datetime.strptime('Sep21', '%b%y')
# datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 1, 0, 0)
```

You could fix the string to keep only 3 letters:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.replace(r'(?<=...).*(?=..)', '', regex=True),
               format='%b%y')
```

or `.replace(r'(?<=...)\D*', '', regex=True)`

output:

```
0   2021-08-01
1   2021-09-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```